# Gitlab does not load assets

Tags: git, apache, gitlab

Gitlab does not load assets. I am using Gitlab 5.0 with Apache server.

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming you use ProxyPass and relative path.

1. Stop GitLab service
2. Run this in your /home/git/gitlab folder :
   `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=/gitlab`
   (Make sure to replace /gitlab to whatever you have given in unicorn.rb)
3. Start the service

A thread you can refer: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gitlabhq/BuaaCHoYoPo